# How to make fullcalendar do a selection twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I want to make two selections in the calendar. Right now I can only make one that goes to one of my inputs.

I am trying to select a date on the calendar, then that first selection goes to my first input tag.

Then after that I want to select a different date that goes to my second input tag.

So basically, I want to make two selections. Here is my code. Do I need to make a callback somewhere here? I put my code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stasis/RRyME/).

```
        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month'
        },
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end, allDay) {
            var title = 'true';
            if (title === 'true') {
                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay
                    },
                    true // make the event "stick"
                );
            var eventStart = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "MM/dd/yyyy");
            var eventEnd = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "MM/dd/yyyy");
            $('input[name="startDate"]').val(eventStart);
            }
            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', calEvent._id);
            $('input[name="startDate"]').removeAttr('value');
            $('input[name="endDate"]').removeAttr('value');
        },
        editable: true
    });
```

Comment: Not clear on your scenario. Would help if you included markup that we could reference to understand visually what's going on (jsfiddle for the markup would be ideal.)

Comment: The jfiddle is in the question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm not understanding your question, how about doing this?

```
if($('input[name="startDate"]').val()=='') {
   $('input[name="startDate"]').val(eventStart);
} else {
   $('input[name="endDate"]').val(eventEnd);
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RRyME/5/)

Comment: Thanks greener for your help. Brain fart.